# Qt application doesn't work but only at power-up (qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display)

Tags: qt, yocto, systemd

I've a Qt application for embedded device yocto based and if I run the application via Qt IDE or deploy it on device and reun via shell command, I don't have problem.
Now I try to use systemd to run the application in device power-up and the application doesn't start and `systemctl status startsystem.service` shows :

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized.
Available platform plugins are : eglfs, minimal ,minimalegl,offscreen,vnc, wayland-egl,wayland.
```

In my YOCTO recipes I've a startsystem.service file :

```
[Unit]
Description=Start the startup script
After=weston.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment="XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0"
ExecStart=/home/root/start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

and a start.sh script where I've the shell command to run the application.
If I run the script after the boot, the Qt application goes up

So Qt application is weel made and the YOCTO platform is consistecy but I suppose to synchronizing some service, but what and how

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

I've update my *.service file in this way :

```
[Unit]

Description=Start the startup script

After=weston.service

[Service]

Environment="XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0"

WorkingDirectory=/opt/Master/bin/

ExecStart=/opt/Master/bin/Master -platform wayland-egl

StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]

WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

and works